# assign permission folder to specific group in linux

Tags: linux, command-line

I am new with Linux Command. I want the result as below:

I have two folders and one group already: folderIT, groupIT and folderShare already created.

1. `folderIT` assign permission to only member of `groupIT` to have full permission.

   what is the command to do this ?
2. `folderShare` assign to everyone full access permission.

   what is the command to do this?

I suppose the command is short and easy to understand because I am really new with Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `man chmod` will give you the answers...

Comment: See http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php Very good explanation with lots of pictures.

Comment: `apropos(1)` will help you to find related commands.
In this case, `apropos permission` will list `chmod` as Jean-Baptiste Yunès suggested, like this:
_chmod (2)            - change permissions of a file_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. chmod -R 755 folderIT 2. chmod -R 777 foldershare
```

For commands you should always check the man page.